Как подключиться с помощью Selenium, Puppeteer, Playwright и т.п. к вкладке браузера, выбранной вручную
Знаю точно, что такое возможно в Selenium Basiс (уже устаревшей версии) и Rufaydium. Однако эти варианты не работают с современными языками программирования.
Возможно ли такое в одном из аналогичных систем, применяющихся при тестировании (Как подключиться с помощью Selenium, Puppeteer, Playwright и т.п. к вкладке браузера, выбранной вручную).
То есть открыто несколько вкладок (открыты в текущей сессии Selenium и т.п.). Вы перешли вручную с активной в Selenium и т.п. Как теперь заставить Selenium и т.п. найти ее и выполнить на ней какие-либо действия.
Спасибо, если кто подскажет хотя бы в каком направлении можно искать.
